# Как засунуть в html переменную из node express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Например сервер выдает ответ, красивой страницей html, в которой есть поле в котором нужно вывести сам ответ, ответ хранится в переменной node.
(например ошибку, или обработанную информацию вообще любую инфу)
Ответ может быть json.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант в лоб - `res.end('<html код ... .... '+переменная+' ... ... итд</html>');`

Либо воспользуйтесь [каким-либо шаблонизатором](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Answer (score 1):

Angular прекрасно справляется с этой задачей

Получаем данные из JSON:

```
productsModule.controller("AutorisationController", function ($scope,$http,$rootScope) {
var obj;

$scope.login = function () {

    $http.post('/login', $scope.user).then(function (response) {
        //  alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));



         if(response.data == false ){
            alert("wrong username or password");
            //  window.location = "/?#/register";
         }else if(response.data.username.length>0){



             //$scope.userinfo = ;
             window.location = "/?#/userPage";
             obj=response.data.username;
             $rootScope.$emit("userinfo", obj);
         }
    });

}

});
```

перекидываем данные в параллельный контроллер:

```
productsModule.controller("UserController", function ($scope, $http,$rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on('userinfo', function (event, data) {
    $rootScope.obj=data;
});

})
```

Вставляем в HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="UserController">
            <li>
                <p class="navbar-text">Welcome {{obj}}   </p>
            </li>

        </ul>
```